# For a connected set $S,$ we all boundary points of $S$ accumulation points?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, connectedness

While I was studying complex analysis, I thought that $\operatorname{bd}(S)$ of a connected set $S$ could be a subset of all accumulation point set of $S.$ Is that true?

Comment: Do you mean "Is it **possible** that $\operatorname{bd}(S)$ is a subset of the accumulation points of $S$?" (which is what you ask in the body of the question) or do you mean "Is it **necessary** that $\operatorname{bd}(S)$ is a subset of the accumulation points of $S$?" (as you seem to ask in the title)?  (the former is trivial when you realize it's possible the boundary is empty)

Comment: consider $\{x_0\}$ for any $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual topology.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $S$ is a connected subspace and has more than one member.

Suppose $x\in\overline S$ and $x$ has a nbhd $U$ such that $U\cap S$ is countable (i.e. finite or countably infinite).

Take $r>0$ such that $A=^{def}\{y:0< |y-x|<r\}\subseteq U.$ Then $A\cap S$ is  not empty (else either $x\in S$ and $S$ is disconnected, or $x\not\in \overline S$) . So take $y_1\in A\cap S.$

Now $\{r'\in (0,|y_1-x|): \exists y\in S\,(|y-x|=r'\}$ is only countable, but $(0,|y_1-x|)$ is uncountable. So take $r''\in (0,|y_1-x|)$ such that $\forall y\in S\,(|y-x|\ne r'').$

Now $\{y\in S: |y-x|<r''\}$ is not empty (as before, otherwise either $x\in S$ and $S$ is disconnected, or $x\not\in\overline S$). And  $\{y\in S: |y-x|>r''\}$ is not empty because it contains $y_1$.

But now $\{y\in S: |y-x|<r''\}$ and $\{y\in S: |y-x|>
r''\}$ are non-empty disjoint open subsets of the space $S,$ and their union is $S$, contrary to $S$ being connected.